# Is there any general formula that describes the sum and difference of Lambert W Function?

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w

I know $\ln(a)+\ln(b)=\ln(ab)$ and $\ln(a)-\ln(b)=\ln(\frac{a}{b})$  or $\ln(a^{b}) = b\ln(a)$ and other rules for the ln (Natural Logarithm). But are there any sum or difference laws for the lambert W Function (Product Log) i.e. any general formula for
$W(x) + W(y)$ or $W(x) - W(y)$ and so on.

Comment: Seems unlikely. $W$ is not a simple function.

Comment: Not a simple formula, but for example $W(z)$ satisfies the differential equation $W'(z)=\dfrac{W(z)}{z(1+W(z))}$

Comment: A "sum formula" of the type you suggest appears on the Wikipedia page for the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Identities).  It's also equation (11) on its [MathWorld page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\begin{align}
W(x) + W(y) &= W\Big(\big(W(x)+W(y)\big)e^{W(x)+W(y)}\Big)\\
&= W\Big(W(x)e^{W(x)+W(y)}+W(y)e^{W(x)+W(y)}\Big)\\
&= W\Big(W(x)e^{W(x)}e^{W(y)} + W(y)e^{W(y)}e^{W(x)}\Big)\\
&= W\Big(xe^{W(y)} + ye^{W(x)}\Big)\\
&= W\bigg(\frac{xy}{W(y)}+\frac{xy}{W(x)}\bigg)\\
&= W\bigg(xy\Big(\frac{1}{W(x)} + \frac{1}{W(y)}\Big)\bigg)
\end{align}$$

Is this the kind of formula you're looking for?

Comment: Yah I saw it on Wikipedia also.